# In terminal console, how do you end/close a loop cycle using python? (I want to run the loop, not ending the loop by error please)

Tags: python-3.x

when using the terminal console, i want to quick test a variable in a for loop. But don't know how to "close" the cycle. It keeps me asking for the next line of code.

```
>>> for i in z:
...     print(i)
...
```

In terminal, when I start to write the second line in a loop, it starts with '...', and no matter how many times I press enter, the loop still doesn't end and start with '...'. The only possible way I had found out to exit the loop is to create an error. But I want to end the loop in terminal while being able to run it though.

Comment: Then use a normal exit condition? Some more words could help.

Comment: Just type it in?

Comment: An images of your code is useless. I copied and pasted it into Sublime Text but your program did not run.

Comment: @usr2564301 I'm asking how to run and end a loop in terminal.

Comment: I'm asking for you to not include code as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering from what you there are a few possibilities, so I am just going to address a few of them. A better detail would be useful still for specific answers:

```
# This is if you want to run the loop 5 times
for i in range(5):
    print(i)

# For breaking out of the loop but not the program
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    if(i==2):
        break
# For breaking out of the program, with exit command and not error
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    if(i==2):
        exit()


for i in range(8):
...     print(i)
... <Here you press enter without tab to exit out of loop>
```

Based on edited comments:
this is the added code:
    for i in range(8):
    ...     print(i)
    ...

Comment: Sorry, I want to run it in terminal, which is different from IDE. In terminal, when I start to write the second line in a loop, it'll start with "...", so I don't know how to exit out the loop while running it.

Comment: It is very simple for i in range(8):
...     print(i)
...                  so just press tab for whatever content you want inside the loop, otherwise when the line starts with ... just press enter. '...' does not mean a default tab is there, you just put one tab for whatever you want inside as it is waiting for your call to put it inside loop, a normal <Enter> would just exit it

Comment: Oh...thank you very much. I just found out that I need to press enter 2 times to run.